# Matrix norm equivalence in case of infinite dimension

Tags: matrices, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Following are some of the matrix norm equivalence in case of finite dimensional matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ and $l=\text{rank}(A)$

1. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_{2}\leq\|A\|_{1}\leq\sqrt{m}\|A\|_{2}$
2. $n\|A\|_{\infty}\leq\|A\|_{1}\leq\ \frac{1}{m} \|A\|_{\infty}$
3. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_{F}\leq\|A\|_{1}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\|A\|_{F}$
4. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\|A\|_{1}\leq\|A\|_{2}\leq\sqrt{n}\|A\|_{1}$
5. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_{\infty}\leq\|A\|_{2}\leq\sqrt{m}\|A\|_{\infty}$
6. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{l}}\|A\|_{F}\leq\|A\|_{2}\leq\|A\|_{F}$
7. $\frac{1}{m}\|A\|_{1}\leq\|A\|_{\infty}\leq\frac{1}{n}\|A\|_{1}$
8. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{m}}\|A\|_{2}\leq\|A\|_{\infty}\leq{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_{2}$
9. $\frac{1}{\sqrt{lm}}\|A\|_{F}\leq\|A\|_{\infty}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_{F}$
10. ${\sqrt{m}}\|A\|_{1}\leq\|A\|_{F}\leq\sqrt{n}\|A\|_{1}$
11. $\|A\|_{2}\leq\|A\|_{F}\leq\sqrt{l}\|A\|_{2}$
12. ${\sqrt{n}}\|A\|_{\infty}\leq\|A\|_{F}\leq\sqrt{lm}\|A\|_{\infty}$

Could somebody please tell me what happens to these in the case of infinite dimensional matrix A?

And I also don't know how to prove 10, 11 and 12.

Comment: In finite dimensional spaces all norms are equivalent, in infinite dimensions these provide counterexamples as you increase $l$. Also, you are comparing the $1,2,F$, and $\infty$ norms so there should be $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ inequalities, not actually 12. The remaining 6 ones should be equivalent inequalities.

Comment: @CalvinKhor I am not sure what you mean by $1$,$2$,$F$, and $∞ $ norms  should be $\binom{4}{2} = 6$ inequalities. Can you please explain?

Comment: if you have an inequality $$c |x|_a < |x|_b <  C |x|_a$$ between norms $a,b$ then it is an easy exercise to take each side and rearrange them to get an equivalent inequality
$$ \frac1C |x|_b \leq |x|_a \leq \frac1c |x|_b$$
so half of your inequalities should imply the other half.

Comment: Also how many inequalities do we want? We are comparing $a,b$ norms, so we pick 2 out of the 4 we are considering. Thats what a binomial coefficient is. (Of course if order matters you do indeed get 12 inequalities like you have)

Comment: @CalvinKhor Thanks. Could you also please tell me how can I prove inequality #12?

Comment: Apply what I said above